# get headers from data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have python pandas data frame like this,

```
           0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0        121     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1        112     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
2        102     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
3        121     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
4  client_id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8
5        125     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
```

My column headers are in 5th row, such as client_id and etc..., How to make this row as my df column headers?

Thank you.

Comment: how are you loading this data into the DataFrame. At that step maybe we can add another check for header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.columns = df.loc[4]
df = df.drop(4).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.name = None
print (df)
  client_id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8
0       121    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
1       112    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
2       102    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
3       121    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
4       125    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1
```

More dynamic:

```
idx = df.index[df.iloc[:,0] == 'client_id']
print (idx)
Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')

df.columns = df.loc[idx.item()]
df = df.drop(idx).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.name = None
print (df)
  client_id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8
0       121    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
1       112    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
2       102    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
3       121    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
4       125    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1
```

Comment: command to get 4 ?? if i have bigger data set, I wouldn't know in which line it is, then how to do? please suggest

Comment: so all data are numeric, only header row is not numeric?

Comment: no, column values can be string, If you can help to get position of client_id, that will do, and making that row as headers. that will do